# Intent from intent activity not working on Android 4.4 but working on android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to integrate the ringtones maker from the Ringdroid to my app.
I have called the ringdroid from my app to the RingtoneSelector activity like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingdroidSelectActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```

I have test on android 6, my editor activity on the RingtoneSelector activity working well. But when I tried with android 4.4 nothing show, it's like through an exception from that.
This is the code that start the Editor.

```
private void startRingdroidEditor() {
    Cursor c = mAdapter.getCursor();
    int dataIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    String filename = c.getString(dataIndex);
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, Uri.parse(filename));
        intent.putExtra("was_get_content_intent", mWasGetContentIntent);
        intent.setClassName( "com.ringdroid", "com.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Ringdroid", "Couldn't start editor");
    }
}
```

Anyone have an ideal about this? Please help me.
More over, the Screen that I call from my activity to the RingroidSeclect Activity, none of the menu items working, like search, and about menu... I have already apply the original themes to the activity.

Comment: donot use `getApplicationContext()` in intent. use activity context

Comment: I have tried that, but it's still not working. I have changed to: 
                        Intent myIntent=new Intent(this, RingdroidSelectActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);